# CXF websevice error

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jboss7.x

I am getting an error when calling a web service after migrating from jboss 5.1.0 to Jboss 7' .

I am using SoapUI for testing the service, the tool generates the following request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:end="http://endpoint.webservice.dtm.ebrd.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <end:OperationFind>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <opId></opId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <opName></opName>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <olName></olName>
         </arg0>
      </end:OperationFind>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

the response I get 

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: For input string: ""</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

there is xml attribute which I have changed to nillable now.

```
@XmlElement(name = "opId", nillable = true)
protected Long opeId;

The wsdl looks like

  <xs:complexType name="GetOperationListRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="opId" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="opName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="olName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

I would expect a null value for opId to be fine but getting a NumberFormatExceptiona dn thus unmarshalling error, this was working fine in Jboss 5 which used Jaxb libraray but I guess in Jboss 7 CXF is used for unmarshalling and marshalling objects. any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: CXF also uses JAXB.  What happens when opId is omitted or with `<opOd/>` ?

Comment: that works fine, but i want minimise the impact on the consumers to minimum due to this  Jboss upgrade